# How to implement IEquatable<Container<T>> in C# for all types T?

Tags: c#, generics, iequatable

I have a simple, generic container class in C# that looks something like this -

```
public class Point<T>
{
    public T Data { get; }
    public string ID { get; }

    public Point(T x, string id)
    {
        this.Data = x;
        this.ID = id;
    }
}
```

I would like all Point objects to be compared solely based on the `ID` property. My question is - how can I implement `IEquatable<Point>` such that any Point objects can be compared to each other? For example, `Point<int>` could be compared to `Point<decimal>`, and the objects would be considered equal if their `ID` properties were identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is to extract a non-generic interface. Though it is not required for `IEquatable`, you can even include the `Data` property in this interface.

```
public interface IPoint {
    object? Data { get; }
    string ID { get; }
}

public class Point<T>: IPoint, IEquatable<IPoint> {
    public T Data { get; }
    
    object? IPoint.Data => Data;
    
    public string ID { get; }

    public Point(T x, string id) {
        this.Data = x;
        this.ID = id;
    }
    
    public bool Equals(IPoint? other) => ID == other?.ID;
    
    public override bool Equals(object? obj) {
        return Equals(obj as IPoint);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Though a caveat is that other code now can provide their own implementation of `IPoint` and their own implementation of `IEquatable<IPoint>`, that isn't consistent with your `Point<T>`. This could cause confusing behaviours such as `implA.Equals(implB)` not agreeing with `implB.Equals(implA)`.

Comment: Could it also work if I extracted a non-generic abstract class with the Id property?

Comment: @Treker Yes, but you can't include the `Data` property in it, and interfaces are generally more flexible - a class can only have one superclass, but can implement multiple interfaces.